# Getting a random value from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a simple app that generates facts. I would like to incorporate a function that generates a random fact instead of incrementing of decrementing.

My array looks like this.

```
public class Facts {
    String facts[] = {
        "Elephants are the only mammals that can't jump.",
        "Candles will burn longer and drip less if they are placed in the freezer a few hours before using.",
        "Potatoes have more chromosomes than humans.",
        "You burn more calories sleeping than you do watching television.",
        "Animals that lay eggs don't have belly buttons.",
    };

String factNumber[] = {
    "Fact 1",
    "Fact 2",
    "Fact 3",
    "Fact 4",
    "Fact 5",
};

public String randomButton() {

    Random r = new Random();
    return facts[i]
}
```

Comment: Did you try `r.nextInt(facts.length)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [random class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). That class has a method, the `nextInt(int n)` ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt())) and quote:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this
>   random number generator's sequence. The general contract of nextInt is
>   that one int value in the specified range is pseudorandomly generated
>   and returned. All n possible int values are produced with
>   (approximately) equal probability...

So, you need a random number that is in fact a random fact, so generate a random number between zero and the facts array size:

#### Example:

```
public String randomButton() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return facts[random.nextInt(facts.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple! Method `nextInt(facts.length)` returns a random integer between 0 and the length of array. Put it as the index of the array to get the random one:

```
Random rnd = new Random()
String randomFact = facts[rnd.nextInt(facts.length)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this also

```
private Integer a = 0;
public String randomButton() {
  Random random = new Random();
  a = random.nextInt(facts.length);
}
String factNumber = facts.a;
```