# Generating random array value Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a simple fact Java Project that generates random facts.
When the random button is clicked, I want to display a random fact, and find that fact number.

```
String factNumber[] = {
            "Fact 1",
            "Fact 2",
            "Fact 3",
            "Fact 4",
            "Fact 5",
};

public String randomButtonNumber() {
            return factNumber[i];
        }

String facts[] = {"Elephants are the only mammals that can't jump.",
            "Candles will burn longer and drip less if they are placed in the freezer a few hours before using.",
            "Potatoes have more chromosomes than humans.",
            "You burn more calories sleeping than you do watching television.",
            "Animals that lay eggs don't have belly buttons.",
};

public String randomButton() {
        Random random = new Random();
        i = random.nextInt(facts.length);
        return facts[random.nextInt(facts.length)];
    }
```

Right now, my code generates a random fact, but the fact number is staying at 1.

Comment: Maybe `return facts[i];`?

Comment: You're calling `Random.nextInt()` twice. Once to store i, and again to get a fact. You should probably only be calling this once.

Comment: Absolutely identical with [Getting a random value from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825021/getting-a-random-value-from-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

You are generating two different numbers. Just use `i`

```
 i = random.nextInt(facts.length);
 return facts[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String randomButton() {
    Random random = new Random();
    i = random.nextInt(facts.length);
    return facts[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your problem. Each time you make a random.next(facts.length) call, it gets you two random numbers and the probability of them being same is less

```
public String randomButton() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return facts[random.nextInt(facts.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remember, facts.length returns how many elements in the array
// and new Random.nextInt() will generate a new result on every call

// These are your facts:

String facts[] = {
    "Elephants are the only mammals that can't jump.",
    "Candles will burn longer and drip less if they are placed in the freezer a few hours before using.",
    "Potatoes have more chromosomes than humans.",
    "You burn more calories sleeping than you do watching television.",
    "Animals that lay eggs don't have belly buttons.",
};


// Here you get a random fact
public String getRandomFactWithNumber() {
    // Generate a random number between 0 and facts.length
    int factNumber = new Random.nextInt(facts.length);

    // Return the fact with its number
    return "Fact " + factNumber + ": " + facts[factNumber];
}

// And if you only want a fact, without the number
public String getRandomFact() {
    // Generate a random number between 0 and facts.length
    int factNumber = new Random.nextInt(facts.length);

    // Return the fact
    return facts[factNumber];
}
```